# Elm Runtime Error when updating page content

Tags: elm

I get this error in elm when I click on a link to switch page :

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

With Firefox, the error message is :

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.removeChild is not an object.
```

What I try to achieve is to make a navigation and load new page content without reloading the page (so make a link without href)

Here is the button:

```
a [ onClick <| SetActivePage Recipes ] [ text "Recipes" ]
```

and in the update I made this:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
  case msg of
    SetActivePage page ->
      case page of
        Recipes ->
          ( { model | page = Recipes }, getRecetteList )


    RecetteMsg subMsg ->
      let
        ( newRecette, subCmd ) =
          Recette.update subMsg model.recette
      in
        ( { model | recette = newRecette }, Cmd.map RecetteMsg subCmd )
```

The error message happens when the model is updated, I have no idea why...

Comment: Did you try deleting `elm-stuff` (or `elm-stuff/build-artifacts`) and rebuilding? Every once in a while if the editor plugins/environment set up in some way, `elm make` might not notice all the changes and produce a result which contain outdated compilations. That's when such weird errors occurred to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Gabor but unfortunately it did not solve my issue :(

Comment: It turns out the problem was caused by external JS lib. "you'll see that error when something other than Elm has messed with the DOM"

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.